# Salvar std::cout em arquivo

Tags: c++, printf, fopen, cout

Preciso adaptar algumas saídas do programa [Ripser](https://github.com/Ripser/ripser). Mais precisamente, preciso fazer o seguinte:

**1.** executando o programa em um exemplo, temos:

```
./ripser examples/random16.lower_distance_matrix
```

cujo output é

```
distance matrix with 15 points
value range: [1,120]
persistence intervals in dim 0:
 [0,1)
 [0,2)
 [0,4)
 [0,5)
 [0,6)
 [0,7)
 [0,8)
 [0,9)
 [0,10)
 [0,11)
 [0,12)
 [0,14)
 [0,15)
 [0,35)
 [0, )
persistence intervals in dim 1:
 [54,56)
 [43,45)
 [37,51)
 [27,56)
 [22,52)
 [21,52)
 [20,59)
 [19,62)
 [18,62)
 [17,60)
 [16,33)
```

**2.** tenho interesse **somente** nas saídas da forma intervalo, ou seja, `[a,b)` ou `[a, )`. Gostaria de salvá-las em um arquivo (eg. `output.txt`).

**3.** Analisando o código `.cpp` busquei por todas as linhas que contêm `[ , )`, as quais apresento abaixo.

```
l. 639   std::cout << " [" << diameter << ", )" << std::endl << std::flush;
l. 651   std::cout << " [" << diameter << "," << death << ")" << std::endl << std::flush;
l. 929   if (get_diameter(e) > 0) std::cout << " [0," << get_diameter(e) << ")" << std::endl;
l. 939   if (dset.find(i) == i) std::cout << " [0, )" << std::endl << std::flush;
```

**4.** Observo que algumas saídas ocorrem dentro de um laço, como por exemplo, a da linha 939, que pode fornecer vários intervalos da forma `[ , )`, dependendo do arquivo de entrada utilizado. Eis o bloco do laço:

```
#ifdef PRINT_PERSISTENCE_PAIRS
        for (index_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            if (dset.find(i) == i) std::cout << " [0, )" << std::endl << std::flush;
#endif
```

### **Minha tentativa**

Para cada uma das 4 linhas citadas acima, usei o código abaixo para escrever a saída em um arquivo, alterando apenas o formato dentro do `fprintf(fp, " ")`.

```
//! [write to file]
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen ("./output", "a+");
fprintf(fp, "0 0 -1\n");
fclose(fp);
```

Isso tem funcionado quase bem, exceto pelo fato de que dentro do laço, apenas uma linha é escrita no output, mesmo nos exemplos onde elas ocorrem na tela repetidas vezes.

Eis o bloco do laço, adaptado.

```
#ifdef PRINT_PERSISTENCE_PAIRS
        for (index_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            if (dset.find(i) == i)
                std::cout << " [0, )" << std::endl << std::flush;
                //! [write to file]
                FILE * fp;
                fp = fopen ("./output", "a+");
                fprintf(fp, "0 0 -1\n");
                fclose(fp);
#endif
```

Um dos outputs que tive foi:

```
0 0 1.013644
0 0 2.838865
0 0 3.131685
0 0 4.077876
0 0 4.725016
0 0 4.818406
0 0 4.924389
0 0 -1
```

no qual podemos ver a última linha, que ocorreu apenas uma vez, mas deveria ter aparecido uma dezena de vezes, devido ao `for (index_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)`.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 2):

Se é C++, use C++.
Veja:

```
std::cout << " [" << diameter << ", )" << std::endl << std::flush;
```

então apenas:

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
std::fstream fs;
fs.open("output.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
fs << " [" << diameter << ", )" << std::endl;
fs.close();
```

A mesma coisa que for printada no console será salva no arquivo.

Dica: no loop crie a instância do fstream e abra o arquivo antes do loop, coloque só para escrever dentro do loop, e feche o arquivo (fs.close()) quando sair do loop.

Comment: Não é necessário usar `std::flush` com `std::endl`, já que o comportamento do segundo é equivalente a `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush'`. Falando nisso, não use `std::endl` deliberadamente! Esse flushing intenso pode causar uma queda significativa no desempenho do programa.